# Draggable overlay on Google Maps in a browser

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have developed an iOS application that allows the user to drag a GMSOverlay subclass around in the Google Maps SDK. The overlay scales with the map as the user zooms in and out.

I want to replicate this in the browser but can't find examples of how to do it. Today I happened to see a web page where this was done.

[Draggable overlay example](https://www.smh.com.au/environment/sustainability/a-billion-kilograms-of-rubbish-in-need-of-a-new-home-20180406-p4z88a.html)

If anyone has any ideas about how this is achieved (generally speaking - I will research from there) it would be appreciated!

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: What about you check [their JS code](https://www.smh.com.au/interactive/2018/china-recycling/story/src/js/mymap.js) and see how they did it?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps API `zoom_changed` event and `getZoom()` method will let you track changes in zoom, which can be used to scale DOM elements.

Comment: this might be a comment but it is not an answer.

Comment: @MrUpsidown This is exactly what OP asked though - just a direction he can look into. I think the question is not very good for a Q/A site in its current form.

Comment: Totally agree with your second statement: Question is not good. In which case, you should vote to close it, possibly add a comment, but not answer it ;)